# Source folder in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have imported the hadoop source code as Java project in Eclipse and in that package names are treated as folders. But when I tried it to run it, it throws "could not find main class". How to change the structure or how to run it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed [the instructions in the BUILDING.txt file](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=hadoop.git;a=blob;f=BUILDING.txt)?

```
Importing projects to eclipse
When you import the project to eclipse, install hadoop-maven-plugins at first.

  $ cd hadoop-maven-plugins
  $ mvn install

Then, generate eclipse project files.

  $ mvn eclipse:eclipse -DskipTests

At last, import to eclipse by specifying the root directory of the project via
[File] > [Import] > [Existing Projects into Workspace].
```

Comment: If I imported like that...can I run the source codes as normal java application